# Creating virtual serial port in Fedora

Tags: linux, java, serial-port

I want to create a virtual serial port in Fedora.  I'm using Java code to communicate over a serial port.  I want to test this code with out any serial devices connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is what you're after:

Virtual Serial Port Driver for Linux
  http://soi.tibbo.com/vspdl.html